# How can I access files on localhost from another laptop in the same network using xampp in ubuntu?

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp on my laptop and I have Ubuntu 12.04.
I tried to access the files on my laptop from android phone by entering
local-ip-address/filename as the URL.
But it shows an error 404 Page does not exist.
Note that I used the local ip address because both are in same network.
I also used my public ip and it still did not work!
Can you tell me the exact procedure to access the files using xampp server in Ubuntu?

Comment: The files need to be in the web root directory( maybe /var/ww/ ). What are you trying to accomplish, a web server or a way to share files?

Comment: Yes, basically a web server! What is this web root directory? Can you tell me more about it? @dan08

Comment: Have you tried Google. There is so much information about this out there, and many tutorials. No point in rehashing it here.

Comment: can you hit local-ip-address fine? or you get 404?

Comment: @LeaTano I get a 404 with local ip too.

Comment: @user2983071 which ip are you using? Can you access from another device/pc? Can you access from the same computer using the internal ip?